# 'Invalid post type' error when importing from one site to another

Tags: posts, errors, import, customization

Our existing corporate site was developed by a 3rd party vendor. I am in the process of creating a new version of our site, in a new WP instance. I need to export the 'News' articles, from the current site, to the new DEV site. My issue is I cannot find, on the current site, where the 'News' custom post type was created/configured. When I click on 'News', in the current site, the post type URL displays as: post_type=recent-news. And, when importing into the new DEV site, I receive this error: 'Invalid post type recent-news'.

1. Does the import custom post type plugin need to be the same as the export custom post type plugin?

I'm using CPT UI on the DEV site, and the only custom post type plugin I can find on the current site is Toolset. but, in the Toolset settings, the only post types that display are OOTB post types of: Media, Pages, and Posts. there is no reference to either 'News' or 'recent-news'.

2. I've tried creating a new custom post type, on DEV, using CPT UI, but I cannot figure out how to specify the post type as 'recent-news', in order to match what is being imported. CPT UI always converts a dash '-' to an underscore '_'?

Am I missing something, or did the 3rd party developer hard code a 'News'/'recent-news' post type somewhere else?

I'm not a true 'developer', I'm more of a front-end guy, so I'm racking my brain trying to figure this out.

Comment: Do you know that the recent-news CPT was created using a plugin at all? It may be created in the theme code itself.

Comment: You can also check the `functions.php` of the active theme for any code that might add the custom post type and get clues from that.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the reply. I don't think it was created using a plugin, as I can't find any reference to 'recent-news' anywhere. I will check the functions file and see if there's a clue there.

Comment: found it, hard coded, in a '/lib/custom.php' Custom Functions file. do I simply add this to the functions.php file, in my Child Theme?

Comment: /* Core Custom Post Type */
add_action('init', 'custom_post_type');
function custom_post_type() {
 global $roots_options;

 // custom
 register_post_type( 'recent-news',
  array(
   'labels' => array(
    'name' => __( 'News' ),
    'singular_name' => __( 'News' ),
    'add_new' => __( 'Create New' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Create New News' ),
    'edit' => __( 'Edit' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit News' ),
    'new_item' => __( 'New News' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( ' Add New News' ),

Comment: 'view' => __( 'View News' ),
    'view_item' => __( 'View News' ),
    'search_items' => __( 'Search News' ),
    'not_found' => __( 'No news found' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No news found in Trash' )
   ),
   'description' => __( 'news will be displayed in news-room' ),
   'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-list-view',
   'public' => true,
   'has_archive' => false,
   'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'archive', 'custom-fields' )
  )
 );

}
/* End Core Custom Post Type */

Comment: I added the code to the DEV 'functions.php' file, re-ran the Import, and all the current site articles are now on the DEV site. I still have a few configuration things to clean-up, but I believe this will work. thank you for the advice!

Comment: Hi Brian, yes you're on the right path - a functions.php file in a CHILD theme (not the parent theme) is the best way to go, OR you can have a custom functions plugin to hold functions that you want to be independent of whatever current Theme is in use.....that's what I do.  So if a function is dependent on the (child) theme it goes into its functions.php file, if not then I have a plugin file that just holds those particular functions.